# REGEX PCRE characters between 2 nth occurrences

Tags: regex, r, pcre

I have data that resembles the following structure. I need to extract the data that is between the third occurrence of "May 2016" and "Jun 2016".

I have the following pattern which (to be frank) is not properly constructed (And it doesn't bring back the characters I want).

```
(.*(?>May 2016)){3}(.*(?=Jun 2016)){3}/s
```

I am new to using Regex, can someone help me with the correct expression please.

> May 2016 ef
>         Jun 2016 efef May 2016 Jun 2016 May 2016
>
> dffdg def efef
>
> Jun 2016
>
> May 2016
>
> Jun 2016

Comment: If you think your regex is not proper, then you have to give an _exact_ representation of what is to be matched. I.e., `May_May_May_<here>Jun_Jun_Jun_` or some combination of such.

Comment: So we can assume that we have "... May 2016 ... Jun 2016 ... May 2016 ... Jun 2016 ..." and so on? I.e. they alternate and start with May?

Comment: You are right in assuming that. also, apologies for not being explicit. What I intend to get from the string is `May 2016 Jun 2016 May 2016 Jun 2016 May 2016 <here> Jun 2016`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one may assume that "May 2016" and "Jun 2016" alternate and the former goes first, then

```
x <- "May 2016 A Jun 2016 B May 2016 Jun 2016 May 2016 C Jun 2016 May 2016 Jun 2016"
sub("(.*?May 2016.*?Jun 2016){2}.*?May 2016(.*?)Jun 2016.*", "\\2", x)
[1] " C "
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (this *requires* `perl = TRUE`):

```
(?s)(?:.*?May 2016){3}\K.*?(?=Jun 2016)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pJ6jC7/1)

Explanation:

- `(?s)` activate the *singleline* option
- `(?:.*?May 2016){3}` match `May 2016` 3 times with random text in-between
- `\K` discard what you've matched so far from the match value
- `.*?` match anything
- `(?=Jun 2016)` ... up to the first occurence of `Jun 2016`

Comment: Will perhaps be helpful after the necessary revision to account for the need of extra escape characters when making R-regex patterns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code and the explanation with the demo. Much helpful. I still wasn't able to exclude the months though. I made the following adjustment to your pattern `(?s)(?:.*?May 2016){3}\K(.*)(?=Jun 2016)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sD7zG5/1)

Comment: Oops sorry I think I answered the question myself. I missed the `?` in the middle  `(?s)(?:.*?May 2016){3}\K(.*?)(?=Jun 2016)` works great

Comment: @Casimir whoops thanks for fixing my stupid mistake, I don't know how I managed to miss that, given that the explanation was for the correct pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

A couple ways

```
tt <- readLines(textConnection("May 2016 ef Jun 2016 efef May 2016 Jun 2016 May 2016

dffdg def efef

Jun 2016

May 2016

Jun 2016"))

(tt <- paste0(tt, collapse = ''))
# [1] "May 2016 ef Jun 2016 efef May 2016 Jun 2016 May 2016dffdg def efefJun 2016May 2016Jun 2016"


m <- gregexpr('May 2016(.*?)Jun 2016', tt, perl = TRUE)
mapply(function(x, y) substr(tt, x, x + y - 1),
       attr(m[[1]], 'capture.start'), attr(m[[1]], 'capture.length'))[3]
# [1] "dffdg def efef"


gsub('May.*May.*May 2016(.*?)Jun 2016.*', '\\1', tt)
# [1] "dffdg def efef"
```